# showing the indeterminate progress bar when opening another activity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I have two layouts, layout A and layout B. There is a button on layout A when clicked, it should take me to layout B, but while taking me to layout B, i want it to show the action bar indeterminate progress bar, after which it displays when the activity is completely loaded, I will like an example please, showing this thank you kindly

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.lyrics);

    getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is that you Load Activity B, then afterwards load the indeterminate progress bar as the Asycntask is retrieving the data for the activity to present. However if you inisit on doing what you want to do, then this code should help you:

```
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    });
```

For more information, please check out the samples on [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) website.

Answer (score 0):

very easy if you use SherlockActionbar

1. download from here

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

1. import to project
2. change extend Activity to SherlockActivity , as for Fragment extend SherlockFragmentActivity
3. call setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(visible);

Comment: @Intahep, i am new to sherlockactionbar, i have done this but the progress bar won't just disappear after activity B loads, i want the progress bar to disappear after the activity B loads

Comment: you have to call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); (before setContentView)

Comment: sorry i mean disappear, it should disappear when the second activity loads

Comment: call setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); for disappear

Comment: thank you for you effort but its not even showing again after adding this code, what i want it to do is showing when my second activity is loading then when is fully loads it disappear

Comment: you can call setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility every single time you want to show/hide ProgressBarIndeterminate, true for show false for hide